# Server/Client in Python Socket program stalls in middle of execution

Tags: python, multithreading, sockets

I am working on an assignment that entails socket-programming using Python. What I am trying to do is create a server called "dispatcher" and 3 clients that all run the same "car.py" file that will represent race cars. Each of the race cars will randomly select a speed between 0-120 mph every five seconds and send that speed to the server(aka dispatcher). The server will take the speeds of the three cars and compute how much distance is left until that car reaches the finish line. Once one or more cars reaches the finish line, the server will compute who the winner is and announce that to all three cars. The server will keep track of who is in the lead and will announce that to all three cars every five seconds.

The problem is that in the middle the program stalls and it seems that the server and one of the clients is both waiting for each other. Here is my code for the server:

```
    import socket
    import sys
    import threading
    from queue import Queue
    
    NUMBER_OF_THREADS = 2
    JOB_NUMBER = [1, 2]
    queue = Queue()
    all_connections = []
    all_address = []
    
    
    # Create a Socket ( connect two computers)
    def create_socket():
        try:
            global host
            global port
            global s
            host = '127.0.0.1'
            port = 9999
            s = socket.socket()
    
        except socket.error as msg:
            print("Socket creation error: " + str(msg))
    
    
    # Binding the socket and listening for connections
    def bind_socket():
        try:
            global host
            global port
            global s
            print("Binding the Port: " + str(port))
    
            s.bind((host, port))
            s.listen(5)
    
        except socket.error as msg:
            print("Socket Binding error" + str(msg) + "\n" + "Retrying...")
            bind_socket()
    
    
    # Handling connection from multiple clients and saving to a list
    # Closing previous connections when server.py file is restarted
    
    def accepting_connections():
        for c in all_connections:
            c.close()
    
        del all_connections[:]
        del all_address[:]
    
        while True:
            try:
                conn, address = s.accept()
                s.setblocking(1)  # prevents timeout
    
                all_connections.append(conn)
                all_address.append(address)
    
                print("Connection has been established :" + address[0])
    
            except:
                print("Error accepting connections")
    
    
    def start_turtle():
        while True:
            cmd = input('turtle> ')
            if cmd == 'go':
                start_race()
            elif cmd == 'stop':
                break
            else:
                print("Command not recognized")
    
    
    # Starting the Race
    def start_race():
        # Setting the distance to the finish line of the three cars
        distance1, distance2, distance3 = 50, 50, 50
        try:
            while True:
                # Collecting Speed rates at MPH of the 3 cars
                speed1 = all_connections[0].recv(4096)
                speed2 = all_connections[1].recv(4096)
                speed3 = all_connections[2].recv(4096)
    
                print("\nSpeed of Car 1: " + str(speed1.decode("utf-8")))
                print("Speed of Car 2: " + str(speed2.decode("utf-8")))
                print("Speed of Car 3: " + str(speed3.decode("utf-8")) + "\n")
    
                # Calculating the distance travelled by each car driving at the same speed for five minutes.
                dist_travelled1 = int(speed1.decode("utf-8")) / 60 * 5
                dist_travelled2 = int(speed2.decode("utf-8")) / 60 * 5
                dist_travelled3 = int(speed3.decode("utf-8")) / 60 * 5
    
                # The amount of distance that is left to reach the finish line.
                distance1 -= round(dist_travelled1, 1)
                distance2 -= round(dist_travelled2, 1)
                distance3 -= round(dist_travelled3, 1)
    
                # Seeing who is in the lead.
                lead = min(distance1, distance2, distance3)
                lead_flag = True
    
                # Checking to see if Car1 won or not
                if distance1 <= 0:
                    message1 = "You crossed the finish line!"
                    print("Car 1 crossed the finish line!")
                    all_connections[0].sendall(message1.encode("utf-8"))
                    lead_flag = False
                else:
                    message1 = "You have " + str(round(distance1, 1)) + " more miles left to go."
                    print("Car 1 has " + str(round(distance1, 1)) + " more miles left to go.")
                    all_connections[0].sendall(message1.encode("utf-8"))
    
                # Checking to see if Car2 won or not
                if distance2 <= 0:
                    message2 = "You crossed the finish line!"
                    print("Car 2 crossed the finish line!")
                    all_connections[1].sendall(message2.encode("utf-8"))
                    lead_flag = False
                else:
                    message2 = "You have " + str(round(distance2, 1)) + " more miles left to go."
                    print("Car 2 has " + str(round(distance2, 1)) + " more miles left to go.")
                    all_connections[1].sendall(message2.encode("utf-8"))
    
                # Checking to see if Car3 won or not
                if distance3 <= 0:
                    message3 = "You crossed the finish line!"
                    print("Car 3 crossed the finish line!")
                    all_connections[2].sendall(message3.encode("utf-8"))
                    lead_flag = False
                else:
                    message3 = "You have " + str(round(distance3, 1)) + " more miles left to go."
                    print("Car 3 has " + str(round(distance3, 1)) + " more miles left to go.")
                    all_connections[2].sendall(message3.encode("utf-8"))
    
                # Breaking from while loop if we have a winner.
                if message1 == "You crossed the finish line!" or message2 == "You crossed the finish line!" or \
                        message3 == "You crossed the finish line!":
                    break
    
                # Keeping track of who is in the lead
                if lead_flag:
                    lead_message = ''
                    if lead == distance1:
                        lead_message = "\nCar 1 is in the lead!"
                    elif lead == distance2:
                        lead_message = "\nCar 2 is in the lead!"
                    elif lead == distance3:
                        lead_message = "\nCar 3 is in the lead!"
                    print(lead_message)
                    all_connections[0].sendall(lead_message.encode("utf-8"))
                    all_connections[1].sendall(lead_message.encode("utf-8"))
                    all_connections[2].sendall(lead_message.encode("utf-8"))
                    sys.stdout.flush()
    
            # If multiple cars crossed the finish line during the last round, calculate who crossed the finish line first.
            time_to_cross_finish1 = distance1 / (dist_travelled1 / 5)
            time_to_cross_finish2 = distance2 / (dist_travelled2 / 5)
            time_to_cross_finish3 = distance3 / (dist_travelled3 / 5)
    
            # Determine the winner
            winner = min(time_to_cross_finish1, time_to_cross_finish2, time_to_cross_finish3)
    
            # Creating and sending messages to both winners and losers.
            loser_message = "You Lost!"
            winner_message = "You Won!"
            if winner == time_to_cross_finish1:
                print("Car 1 Won!")
                all_connections[0].sendall(winner_message.encode("utf-8"))
                all_connections[1].sendall(loser_message.encode("utf-8"))
                all_connections[2].sendall(loser_message.encode("utf-8"))
            elif winner == time_to_cross_finish2:
                print("Car 2 Won!")
                all_connections[0].sendall(loser_message.encode("utf-8"))
                all_connections[1].sendall(winner_message.encode("utf-8"))
                all_connections[2].sendall(loser_message.encode("utf-8"))
            elif winner == time_to_cross_finish3:
                print("Car 3 Won!")
                all_connections[0].sendall(loser_message.encode("utf-8"))
                all_connections[1].sendall(loser_message.encode("utf-8"))
                all_connections[2].sendall(winner_message.encode("utf-8"))
        except:
            print("Error: Shutting Down")
    
    
    # Create worker threads
    def create_workers():
        for _ in range(NUMBER_OF_THREADS):
            t = threading.Thread(target=work)
            t.daemon = True
            t.start()
    
    
    # Do next job that is in the queue (handle connections, send commands)
    def work():
        while True:
            x = queue.get()
            if x == 1:
                create_socket()
                bind_socket()
                accepting_connections()
            if x == 2:
                start_turtle()
    
            queue.task_done()
    
    
    def create_jobs():
        for x in JOB_NUMBER:
            queue.put(x)
    
        queue.join()
    
    
    create_workers()
    create_jobs()
```

And for the cars (All three clients run the same file):

```
    import random
    import time
    import socket
    import sys
    
    # create an INET(IPv4), STREAMing(TCP) socket
    try:
        s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    except socket.error:
        print('Failed to create socket')
        sys.exit()
    
    print('Socket Created')
    
    host = '127.0.0.1'
    port = 9999
    
    s.connect((host, port))
    print('Socket Connected to IP' + host)
    
    
    # Function for calculating current speed
    def speed():
        # Using random number to determine speed group
        marker = random.randrange(1, 100)
        speed_ratio = ''
    
        # Speed groups are chosen before actual speed in order to balance speed selection and make the program more
        # realistic.
        if marker == 1:
            speed_ratio = 'Crash'
        elif marker < 5:
            speed_ratio = 'Too_Slow'
        elif marker < 15:
            speed_ratio = 'Slow'
        elif marker < 65:
            speed_ratio = 'Steady'
        elif marker < 90:
            speed_ratio = 'Fast'
        elif marker < 100:
            speed_ratio = 'Ultra_Fast'
        elif marker == 100:
            speed_ratio = 'Max_Speed'
    
        # Based on ratio, exact speed is determined in mph
        speed_range = {'Crash': 0,
                       'Too_Slow': random.randrange(1, 29),
                       'Slow': random.randrange(30, 59),
                       'Steady': random.randrange(60, 79),
                       'Fast': random.randrange(80, 109),
                       'Ultra_Fast': random.randrange(110, 119),
                       'Max_Speed': 120}
    
        # Current speed is printed and sent to the server
        current_speed = speed_range[speed_ratio]
        print("\nCurrent Speed: " + str(current_speed))
        s.sendall(str(current_speed).encode("utf-8"))
    
        # Waits to receive calculation of how close it is to the finish line.
        reply = s.recv(4096)
        message = reply.decode("utf-8")
        print(message)
    
        # Waits to receive news of who is in the lead or who the winner is.
        reply = s.recv(4096)
        message = reply.decode("utf-8")
        print(message)
    
        # Exit upon winning or losing
        if message == "You Won!" or message == "You Lost!":
            return False
    
        return True
    
    
    # Main program: Calculates speed every five seconds. Each second represents what would be a minute in real time.
    flag = True
    now = time.time()
    future = now + 5
    while flag:
        if time.time() > future:
            flag = speed()
            now = time.time()
            future = now + 5
```

Here is what the console reads from the server program:

> turtle: Binding the Port: 9999 Connection has been established
> :127.0.0.1 Connection has been established :127.0.0.1 Connection has
> been established :127.0.0.1 go
>
> Speed of Car 1: 20 Speed of Car 2: 85 Speed of Car 3: 4
>
> Car 1 has 48.3 more miles left to go. Car 2 has 42.9 more miles left
> to go. Car 3 has 49.7 more miles left to go.
>
> Car 2 is in the lead!

Here are the three client terminals:

Car 1:

> Socket Created Socket Connected to IP127.0.0.1
>
> Current Speed: 20 You have 48.3 more miles left to go.
>
> Car 2 is in the lead!
>
> Current Speed: 113

Car 2:

> Socket Created Socket Connected to IP127.0.0.1
>
> Current Speed: 85 You have 42.9 more miles left to go.
>
> Car 2 is in the lead!
>
> Current Speed: 78

Car 3:

> Socket Created Socket Connected to IP127.0.0.1
>
> Current Speed: 4 You have 49.7 more miles left to go. Car 2 is in the
> lead!

As you can see from the output, Car 1 and Car 2 have produced another speed that was sent to the server while Car 3 has not. It seems that the server is sitting and waiting for Car 3 and Car 3 is waiting for the server and I don't know why. Car 3 implements the same exact code as the other cars. When I rerun the program it *usually* gets stuck at Car 3 but will sometimes get stuck at Car 2 and even Car 1 in the same way.

I am baffled at what the problem could be. It actually worked one single time after repeatedly rerunning the program but after rerunning right away after that with no changes whatsoever, it went back to this same problem. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Don't have much python, but calls like 'reply = s.recv(4096)' worry me.  Due to the octet-streaming nature of TCP, recv() can return having loaded only one byte, even though sendall has sent many mkre.  Unless you apply a protocol on top of TCP, you cannot transfer messages longer than one byte in a reliable fashion.